# 4 apples, 2 worms - probability

Tags: probability

Well I'm still going to school and I read that this forum is for ANY level so I hope you can answer my question.

I got probability in school and the task is the following (poorly translated) :

"You have 4 apples, 2 of them have worms. You take 2 apples at once. What is the probability that you just took the two apples with worms?"

I thought hmm.. 4 apples total? 2 Apples with worms so 
P(both apples have worms) = 2/4.

The correct answer is 1/6, but why?

Comment: Look, Davlog, in 6 minutes time you got four answers. Different approaches from combinatorics to standard probability rules to someone writing all combinations out for you. But do you understand your mistake? That's equally important. If you are learning from a Stats book, read about probability with or without replacement (Here it is without) I think that will answer a great deal of your question!

Comment: @imranfat Yeah, now I do understand my mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: Then there's this old joke: What is worse than finding a worm in an apple? Answer: Half a worm!

Comment: @martycohen haha, nice one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's name the apples $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. How many different ways are there of choosing two apples?
$$A\text{ and }B\\\\ A\text{ and }C\\\\ A\text{ and }D\\\\ B\text{ and }C\\\\ B\text{ and }D\\\\ C\text{ and }D$$
There are $6$ ways of choosing two apples. Only $1$ of these ways will be the one in which **both** of the wormy apples are chosen. Therefore the probability is $1/6$.

I recommend reading [the Wikipedia article on binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). In general, the number of ways of choosing $k$ things out of $n$ things (where the order of the choice doesn't matter) is
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
where $m!$ denotes the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of $m$. We can see that this matches our result above: the number of ways of choosing $k=2$ things out of $n=4$ things is
$$\frac{4!}{(4-2)!2!}=\frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}=\frac{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{(2\times 1)\times(2\times 1)}=6$$

Answer (score 7):

The probability of picking *one* apple with a worm is $\dfrac 24$ (since two of the four apples have a worm). Then, after having already picked an apple with a worm, there are then three apples left, only one of which has a worm. So the probability of picking a *second* apple with a worm is $\dfrac 13$.

Multiplying the probabilities gives us the probability of picking both apples with worms

$$\dfrac 12 \times \dfrac 13 = \dfrac 16$$

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ pairs of apples that may be chosen, and there is only one pair that *both* have worms.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you pick the second apple, you did not put the first apple back. So for the first apple you got your 2/4 for the first apple with worms, and and second one 1/3 with worms. Multiply gives the answer.